# Expression Templates in D

Tags: d, template-meta-programming

The goal is to achieve the same effect as in [this C++ example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates): avoid creating temporaries.  I've tried translating the C++ example to D without success.  I've also tried different approaches.

```
import std.datetime : benchmark;
import std.stdio    : writefln, writeln;

void bench(alias fun, string time = "msecs")(string msg, uint n = 1_000_000) {
  auto b = benchmark!fun(n);
  writefln(" %s: %s ms", msg, b[0].to!(time, int));
}

alias double Real;

struct Expression(string op, E1, E2) {
  E1 _v1;
  E2 _v2;
  alias _v1 v1;
  alias _v2 v2;

  auto opIndex(size_t i) {
    return mixin("v1[i]" ~ op ~ "v2[i]");
  }

  auto opBinary(string op, E)(auto ref E e) {
    return Expression!(op, typeof(this), E)(this, e);
  }
}

struct ExpVector {

  Real[40] _data = void;
  alias _data this;

  this(Real datum) pure nothrow { _data = datum; }

  auto opBinary(string op, T)(auto ref T other) {
    return Expression!(op, typeof(this), T)(this, other);
  }

  void opAssign(E)(auto ref E exp) {
    foreach(i, ref datum; _data)
      datum = exp[i];
  }
}

struct Vector {

  Real[40] _data = void;
  alias _data this;

  this(Real datum) pure nothrow { _data = datum; }

  auto opBinary(string op)(auto ref Vector other) {
    Vector ret;
    foreach(i, datum; _data)
      ret[i] = mixin("datum" ~ op ~ "other[i]");
    return ret;
  }
}

void main() {

  ExpVector e1 = ExpVector(1.5);
  ExpVector e2 = ExpVector(7.3);
  ExpVector ef;
  void T1() {
    ef = (e1 + e2) * (e1 + e2);
  }
  bench!T1(" vector operations using template expression");

  Vector v1 = Vector(1.5);
  Vector v2 = Vector(7.3);
  Vector vf;
  void T2() {
    vf = (v1 + v2) * (v1 + v2);
  }
  bench!T2(" regular vector operations");

  void T3() {
    for(int i = 0; i < vf.length; ++i)
      vf[i] = (v1[i] + v2[i]) * (v1[i] + v2[i]);
  }
  bench!T3(" what is expected if template expressions worked and temporaries were not created.");
}
```

The expression template version is slower than the non-expression template version.  I was expecting the expression template version to be much faster and close to what is expected.  So what is wrong with my expression templates?  What's the correct way to do expression template in D?

Comment: Well, without even considering what the code does, I would point out that you would need to compile the code on a compiler which shares a backend with the C++ compiler to be able really compare the language rather than the compiler implementation. If you use gdc for the D stuff and gcc for the C++ stuff, you'll get a much better comparison of the language itself. The D code could be slower simply because dmd's backend doesn't optimize as well as gcc's does. There could easily be more to it to that, but comparing dmd vs gcc could easily just be comparing the optimizers of the two compilers.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what I said.  The code I've posted is more than twice as slow as the version without expression template, i.e., just a regular `Vector` struct that implements the `opBinary` member function, with both versions compiled with DMD.  I'm not comparing it to the C++ code in Wikipedia.

Comment: Then you should post both versions. It's hard to compare something to something else when you only have one of the two.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis I have posted the complete program.

Comment: You might try this trick see if you can do away with even the structs: http://arrayboundserror.blogspot.com/2009/03/i-just-got-free-25-speedup-in-my-code.html

Answer (score 2):

In wikipedia's c++ example expression classes holds references to temporaries, and in case of expression...

`Vec a, b;
double c;
Vec result = ( a - b ) * c`

...right before assignment to result vector we have some sort of tree in memory:
`a           b
 \        /
  \      /
   \    /
 VecDifference
      \
       \
        \
       VecScaled( has copy of 'c' embedded directly in object )`

VecDifference hold just **references** to a and b, and VecScaled holds **reference** to temporary VecDifference (which, according to the c++ rules, will be alive until expression end). At the end we have no duplication of initial data and no unnecessary computations(if we will use just some components of vector, but not all of them as in simple assignment to Vec)
In your struct Expression(string op, E1, E2) initial and intermediate data simply copied to data members and at the end of previous expression you will have

`Expression!( "*", Expression!( "-", Vec, Vec ), double )`

where outer Expression will have **copy** of inner Expression( "-", Vec, Vec ) and double parameters and inner Expression will have **copies** of a and b vectors. So at the end of a day you avoided temporary Vec but made 4 copies of a and b (not counting final assignment to result vector).
Though, don't know how nicely avoid copying in this situation in D. Maybe pointers to structres ?
(BTW, c++11's auto type inference and expression templates with references to temporaries has unfortunate interaction, which can lead to bugs: http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/inferring-too-much/)

Comment: I was aware of the copying, but D won't let me have them as reference.  I did try pointer (I was under the impression that would make my code unsafe) and it does make a big difference, but still not quite there.  e.g., the expression template version takes `250ms` while `150ms` is expected.

Comment: Yes, pointers makes things unsafe. Page linked at the end of my answer shows one of such dangers (it's about c++, but I think that we can get same results using expression templates in D with pointers)